# Automating ChromeDriver Management in a GitHub Python Project with Selenium

Tags: github, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to inquire about the best practices for using Selenium's ChromeDriver in a Python project hosted on GitHub. Currently, my approach involves manually uploading the latest ChromeDriver to the project and then specifying the path using chromedriver_path = './chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver'. The issue I encounter is the need for manual uploads every time there is an update. Is there a more efficient way to automate the installation and loading of the latest ChromeDriver version within the GitHub repository? Thanks.

I am currently attempting to find a reliable way to specify the path for ChromeDriver installation in the requirements.txt file using '/usr/bin/chromedriver'. Additionally, I have explored the use of chromedriver-autoinstaller, but unfortunately, both approaches seem to be unsuccessful. Can anyone provide guidance on how to correctly configure the requirements.txt file for installing and managing chromedriver?